# R squared of predicted values

Tags: r, predict

I have a basic issue considering predict function and its R squared value.

```
data<- datasets::faithful
# Linear model
model<- lm (eruptions~., data=data)
summary (model)[[9]] # R squared ajusted

# Creating test data to predict eruption values using the previous model
test.data<- data.frame(waiting= rnorm (80, mean = 70, sd = 14 ))
pred<- predict (model, test.data) # Predict eruptions based and the previou model

# New dataset with predicted values
newdata<- data.frame (eruptions = model.pred, waiting = test.data)

# Linear model to predicted values
new.model<- lm (eruptions~., data = newdata)
summary (new.model)[[9]] ## R-squared from predicted values
```

The R-squared of data set with predicted values is 1. It seems obvious that if the predicted values are based on the same variables used in the predict function, the fit measured by R-squared is perfect (=1). But, my interest would be measure *how good* is my model to *test other datasets*, for example test.data in the code. Am I using predict function correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Pass your new variables as the "newdata" argument of the predict() function.

Type `?predict` in an R console to get its R Documentation:

> newdata
>
> An optional data frame in which to look for variables with
> which to predict. If omitted, the fitted values are used.